# Какие единицы используются при расчете для получения знаков?

Tags: поддержка, знаки

Есть такой знак "ассемблер":

[image: знак ассемблер]

Как видим, до него у меня еще 38 чего-то. Это явно не баллы репутации, т.к. если просуммировать баллы (сумма_голосов*10 + количество_принятых*15) даже с [первой страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=votes&q=user%3a1365%20[assembler]) моих ответов, то их окажется явно больше 100.

Если предположить, что не учитываются баллы за ответы времен Хэшкода, то если считать баллы только за [новые ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1365%20[assembler]), допустим, начиная с февраля этого года, их все равно окажется больше 100.

Также я думал о варианте "100 баллов в среднем за ответ", но тогда у меня должно было получиться где-то 20-30 баллов в среднем.

Я думаю, что учитываются именно голоса (просто голоса, а не баллы) на конец суток, т.к. общее количество голосов - 64, что уже ближе к истине.

Хотелось бы прояснить ситуацию и понять, какие единицы учитываются при подсчете для получения знака?

**Обновление**

Я акцентирую внимание именно на формулировке: "62/100 балла **репутации**" и "не менее 100 баллов **рейтинга**". Вопрос с репутацией можно считать закрытым, т.к. перевод уже исправлен, но остается другая проблема: необходимо явное определение термина "рейтинг", т.к. сходу не поймешь, что рейтинг - это грубо говоря сумма голосов (с учетом отрицательных), а не репутация.

Comment: В "62/100 балла репутации" ошибка. [Вот эти строки в Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/50034011?q=%24Score%24%2F%24ScoreRequired%24%20score). Хотел исправить, но меня опередил VladD. =)

Comment: Поскольку перевод уже поправили на рейтинг, подредактировал заголовок вопроса. В будущем его вероятнее всего будут искать именно так.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в результате изменился смысл вопроса. Ту информацию, которую вы дали в своем ответе, я могу найти в справке. Меня сбила с толку именно "репутация" и отсутствие явного определения понятия "рейтинг".

Comment: часть информации, которую я дал в своем ответе, нигде не отражена в справке. Она есть только на двух англоязычных метах. За основу я взял ответ [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395) и добавил некоторые собственные наблюдения.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, эта информация, безусловно, полезна, но это, к сожалению, ответ не на мой вопрос.

Comment: Не прошло и года, как я дополнил ответ. Надеюсь, теперь он отвечает на ваш вопрос чуть больше )

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Что такое рейтинг по метке

Это мера вклада участника в ответы на вопросы с данной меткой. Отличное определение [даётся в соседнем ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1704/181472):

> Баллы за метку — это сумма всех оценок за ответы, которые не удалены и не отмечены общими (отрицательные оценки тоже учитываются).

- Рейтинг не равен репутации и не имеет с ней линейной связи;
- Рейтинг есть и на Мете, где репутация вообще отсутствует;
- Рейтинг может быть отрицательным.

## За что, как и когда начисляется рейтинг по метке

- Рейтинг по метке пересчитывается раз в сутки, примерно в полночь по серверному времени;
- Рейтинг даётся только за ответы, но не за вопросы и не за принятие ответа ("галочку").
- За каждый голос "за" на ответе даётся единица рейтинга; за каждый голос "против" она отнимается. В общем случае ответ приносит ровно столько рейтинга, какое число стоит между стрелочками. Ответ может давать отрицательный рейтинг.
- Рейтинг начисляется по каждой метке, которая есть на вопросе (до пяти);

  - Если к вопросу была добавлена новая метка, то при пересчёте все ответы принесут своим авторам рейтинг пропорционально голосам;
  - Если метка была удалена, то рейтинг отнимется обратно;
- Рейтинг по метке начисляется только за авторские, не-общие ответы;

  - Если ответ стал общим, то рейтинг за него теряется (в отличие от репутации, которая сохранится за уже полученные голоса, но не будет добавляться за новые);
  - Если вопрос из общего стал авторским (это может сделать модератор или сотрудник), рейтинг снова добавится;
- Если ответ удален, то рейтинг за него более не учитывается. Вроде бы это применимо и к отрицательному рейтингу;

## Для всех знаков:

- По данной метке в целом на сайте должно быть задано не менее 100 вопросов (например, на Мете сейчас всего 4 таких метки);
- Если рейтинг по метке стал равен или более чем требуемый (и пользователь имеет достаточное количество ответов - 20, 80 или 200), то в момент пересчета пользователь награждается знаком;
- Если рейтинг стал ниже требуемого, то знак отнимается;
- После синонимизации отнимаются знаки второстепенных синонимов (если они были) и остается или даётся знак основного;
- После переименования метки старый знак отнимается и дается новый;
- После удаления метки знак отнимается.

## Бронзовый:

- 100 баллов рейтинга;
- 20 ответов по метке.

## Серебряный:

- 400 баллов рейтинга;
- 80 ответов по метке.

## Золотой:

- 1000 баллов рейтинга;
- 200 ответов по метке.

Answer (score 6):

Баллы за метку — это сумма всех **оценок** за **ответы**, которые **не удалены** и **не отмечены общими** (отрицательные оценки тоже учитываются). Вы можете посмотреть оценки по всем меткам у себя [в профиле на вкладке Активность > метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor?tab=tags).

Вот ваши ответы с меткой [assembler](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembler): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1365+[assembler]+is:a. Считаем: `1 + 1 + 3 + 2 + 5 + 2 + 1 + 4 + 4 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 4 + 0 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 1 + 3 + 0 + 1 = 64`. Вот ваши баллы. Счётчик обновляется с некоторой задержкой (то ли раз в сутки, то ли раз в несколько часов — не помню), отсюда небольшое расхождение.

Comment: Сумма оценок == сумма голосов (грубо говоря, положительные - отрицательные)? Но это явно не баллы репутации. С формулировкой "баллы рейтинга" я бы тоже поспорил.

Comment: Это я уже понял и сам посчитал. Меня интересует именно формулировка "не менее 100 балла __рейтинга__" и "62/100 балла __репутации__" (см. скриншот в вопросе). В моем понимании, репутация - это [вот это число](http://i.imgur.com/5MA36uy.png), оно считается на основе голосов и принятых ответов (ну еще репутация полученная в качестве награды и прочее). По поводу рейтинга, возможно уже где-то было обсуждение, что им нужно считать сумму голосов, что-то такое припоминаю.

Comment: А интересно (но не настолько, чтобы делать вопрос), "34/20 ответа" -- это что такое?

Comment: @avp Предлагаете записать как "1.7 ответов"?

Comment: @avp: судя по всему: 34 ответа из 20 нужных

Comment: Хотя, наверное, лучше бы так и написать в переводе :)

Comment: @VladD: `$Score$ из $ScoreRequired$ баллов рейтинга`?

Comment: @VladD, теперь наверное понял: обе линии вместе с дробями G1/G0 и A1/A0 говорят -- "для получения знака требуется набрать G0 голосов (у вас G1) в минимум A0 ответах (у вас A1)"

Comment: @avp: абсолютно верно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если честно, никогда раньше не обращал внимания на эту инфу.

Comment: @NickVolynkin "N из M" — нормально, но я думал, что для программистов надпись "N/M" тоже привычна. Впрочем, когда N > M, выглядит странновато, да. Но и "34 из 20" не менее странно.

Comment: @Discord: для меня "N/M" привычно, но за всех не скажу.

Comment: @avp: у вас там назревает золотой значок по плюсам. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это я уже понял.