# Нет строки для перевода "цвета" знака

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex, знаки

По следам вопроса [Какие единицы используются при расчете для получения знаков?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1703/181472)

Остается еще неисправленная ошибка: "тематический знак **Bronze** assembler". В Transifex это строка ["тематический знак $badgeClass$ $tag$"](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40840518?key=1b133144babbd04808205927bb6b8bc2). Явно "Bronze" берется откуда-то еще, причем непереведенной строки я не нашел. У португальцев тоже "Bronze", "Silver", "Gold" ("Gold javascript medalha de tag").

[image: знак ассемблер]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом случае использовалось имя из класса-перечисления, а не локализованная версия строки.

Это исправлено; изменения <s>будут видны в ближайшей сборке (2015.11.9.2952).</s> уже видны.

---

An enumeration name was being used directly in this popup, instead of a localized version.

This has been changed and will be with you in the next build (rev 2015.11.9.2952).

Comment: Thank you! Will it use existing lines for badge colors or add new ones? At this moment the most probable candidate is [string 5117](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267052?key=a0df72576daf9a1137d39f7553d36e82) which is translated in plural and won't fit in this case.

Comment: I don't have access to transifex. I changed the input to the format string, so there shouldn't be any re-translation required (I could have done it differently, but decided to do it this way to avoid re-translation).

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get the "format string" idea. The source in Tx is `$badgeClass$ $tag$ tag badge`. It's the `$badgeClass$` that wasn't translated properly. Which string will be used now?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. I didn't change that source. Just changed what is passed in to `$badgeClass$` to be properly localized (there may be a need to translate those strings, though I'd be surprised if they haven't already been localized).

Comment: Oh, I see. Looks like the translation in plural was wrong and the abovementioned string is only used in this case. The fix is already seen, the translations will come with next update. Thank you again.

Comment: Awesome! Glad this is getting sorted :)

Comment: one more bug of the same sort: [Wrong description for abstract badge tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269110)

Comment: Thanks! Will look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил используемые здесь строки:

- [Bronze](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267052?key=a0df72576daf9a1137d39f7553d36e82) -> <s>Бронзовые</s> Бронзовый
- [Silver](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267052?key=f96e345fdc19cbd4cf15256c251a39a0) -> <s>Серебряные</s> Серебряный
- [Gold](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267052?key=9768feb3fdb1f267b06093bc572952dd) -> <s>Золотые</s> Золотой
- [`$badgeClass$ $tag$ tag badge`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267052?key=1b133144babbd04808205927bb6b8bc2) -> <s>`тематический знак $badgeClass$ $tag$`</s> `$badgeClass$ знак за метку $tag$`

Было так:

> - тематический знак Бронзовые assembler

В ближайшее время станет так:

> - Бронзовый знак за метку assembler
> - Серебряный знак за метку регулярные-выражения
> - Золотой знак за метку c++