# Улучшение перевода термина score/рейтинг

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация

Коллеги, на данный момент у нас есть два параллельных термина: репутация (reputation, rep) и рейтинг (score).

Репутация изменяется на +10 за каждый голос «за» вашему ответу, и на −2 за каждый голос «против». Рейтинг изменяется на +1 за каждый голос «за» вашему ответу, и на −1 за каждый голос «против».

Эти два параллельных термина [приводят к недоразумениям](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1703/10105) (связанным, к сожалению, с моей ошибкой перевода).

**Предложение:** давайте придумаем более хороший перевод для слова score. Термины «репутация» и «рейтинг» достаточно близки, чтобы вызвать путаницу (пример: представьте себе, что у вас есть *координаты* и *положение* пикселя на картинке).

Контекст, в котором употребляется score (и текущий перевод):

- Creating a tag synonym requires $score$ score in this tag → Для создания синонима метки необходимо набрать по ней $score$ баллов рейтинга.
- Answer score of 100 or more → Ответ с рейтингом 100 и более баллов
- Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total → Нулевой рейтинг принятых ответов, более 10 и 25% от общего количества
- Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x → Ответ с наилучшим рейтингом, который обошёл более чем вдвое принятый ответ с рейтингом больше 10
- Answers with the highest score first → Сначала ответы с наивысшим рейтингом
- Vote score (upvotes - downvotes) → Количество голосов («за» — «против»)
- Asked $__count$ non-wiki questions with a total score of $QuestionScore$. → Задал $__count$ авторских вопроса с общим рейтингом, равным $QuestionScore$.
- $Score$/$ScoreRequired$ score → $Score$/$ScoreRequired$ баллов рейтинга (из упомянутого выше вопроса)
- Earn at least $score$ total score for at least $answerScoreStr$ non-community wiki answers in the $tagLink$ tag. These users can single-handedly mark $tagLink$ questions as duplicates and reopen them as needed → Заработать не менее $score$ баллов рейтинга за минимум $answerScoreStr$ ответов, не отмеченных как общие, на вопросы с меткой $tagLink$. Такие пользователи могут самостоятельно отмечать дубликаты среди вопросов с меткой $tagLink$, а также повторно открывать их.

Comment: Пожалуйста, предлагайте варианты перевода только вместе с контекстом!

Comment: А мне очень нравится рейтинг. Постараюсь найти время и подробно объяснить, почему.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Проблема не в самом рейтинге, сам по себе он хорош. Но разницу между баллами рейтинга и баллами репутации (как это у нас сейчас) не поймёт никто.

Comment: я сразу понял когда-то. А insolor не понял из-за ошибки перевода. Ошибка уже исправлена.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Ну это вы :) А если обыкновенный пользователь (ТМ) посмотрит на «100 баллов рейтинга», он подумает, что это 10 плюсов, каждый по 10 баллов, всем же известно. Как, баллы рейтинга и баллы репутации не одно и то же?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Поэтому, возможно, корень проблемы в слове «баллы».

Comment: @VladD: ещё факт в копилку: "100 баллов рейтинга" без контекста  я (ошибочно) воспринял как  10 голосов "за", то есть как 100 очков, а не 1000 (потому что дневная репутация обычно порядка 100, а кол-во голосов за отдельный вопрос редко 10 превышает).

Comment: @jfs: Да, именно этот эффект я и имел в виду. Спасибо!

Comment: То есть, у нас есть репутация/рейтинг и баллы/очки/голоса.

Comment: __Небольшое дополнение__. -1 – голос против (это голос, а не бал рейтинга). Под рейтингом имеется в виду разница голосов «за» и «против» по сообщению.

Answer (score 3):

## голосов

Хотя из этого варианта не очень поятно, что речь именно о разности, а не о плюсах.

- Creating a tag synonym requires $score$ score in this tag → Для создания синонима метки необходимо набрать по ней $score$ голосов.
- Answer score of 100 or more → Ответ набрал 100 голосов
- Answers with the highest score first → Сначала ответы с наивысшим числом голосов
- Vote score (upvotes - downvotes) → Количество голосов («за» — «против»)
- Asked $__count$ non-wiki questions with a total score of $QuestionScore$. → Задал $__count$ авторских вопроса с $QuestionScore$ голосами.
- $Score$/$ScoreRequired$ score → $Score$/$ScoreRequired$ голосов (из упомянутого выше вопроса)
- Earn at least $score$ total score for at least $answerScoreStr$ non-community wiki answers in the $tagLink$ tag. These users can single-handedly mark $tagLink$ questions as duplicates and reopen them as needed → Заработать не менее $score$ голосов за минимум $answerScoreStr$ ответов, не отмеченных как общие, на вопросы с меткой $tagLink$. Такие пользователи могут самостоятельно отмечать дубликаты среди вопросов с меткой $tagLink$, а также повторно открывать их.

Comment: может быть, _Количество голосов («за» минус «против»)_?

Comment: М.б. *Баланс голосов* (хотя, длинновато)

Comment: @avp: "сумма голосов" (как длинный вариант для официальных мест, который в повседневном обсуждении можно просто до "голосов" сокращать)

Comment: @jfs: Может, напишете альтернативным ответом?

Comment: @VladD: "сумма голосов" -- это перевод только для "Vote score", вместо "кол-во голосов".

Comment: Так переводить нельзя. Термин «голоса» закреплён за "votes". Как вы будете переводить "Post has a good score but received delete votes"?

Answer (score -1):

## Рейтинг, при необходимости измеряемый в очках рейтинга

#### (а репутация измеряется в баллах)

Рейтинг — это отличный вариант, *score*. В спортивном смысле это ещё и *счёт*, но такой вариант не будет понятен. И спортивный счёт и рейтинг измеряются полученными очками, если есть необходимость. Но всегда можно сравнивать рейтинг с «сырым» числом, не обозначая единицу измерения.

Рейтинг — это место участника в общей таблице соревнующихся по конкретной метке знатоков. Например, в списке [«Лучшие участники» по конкретной метке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers) показывается именно рейтинг, то есть сумма рейтингов ответов участника.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заметьте, что списки лидеров по репутации, полученной за метку, не формируются.

Рейтинг — это место вопроса в общем списке вопросов, а ответа — среди других ответов. Ответы приносят своему автору ровно столько рейтинга по каждой метке, сколько имеют сами.

Именно рейтинг показывается рядом с вопросом и ответом в виде числа крупным шрифтом. Можно не вдаваться в подробности подсчета рейтинга ответа, если просто знать, что рейтинг пользователя по метке — это сумма чисел рядом с ответами.

Когда говорим о заработанной дельте рейтинга — используем «очки рейтинга».

Когда говорим об общем показателе — просто «рейтинг».

> «репутация» и «рейтинг» достаточно близки, чтобы вызвать путаницу

Не соглашусь. Например, какой-нибудь политик может иметь высокий рейтинг, но плохую репутацию.

#### Перевод в контексте

- Creating a tag synonym requires $score$ score in this tag → Для создания синонима метки необходимо набрать по ней $score$ очков рейтинга.
- Answer score of 100 or more → Ответ с рейтингом 100 и более
- Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total → Принятых ответов с нулевым рейтингом более 10 и 25% от общего количества
- Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x → Ответ с наивысшим рейтингом, который обошёл более чем вдвое принятый ответ с рейтингом больше 10
- Answers with the highest score first → Сначала ответы с наивысшим рейтингом
- Vote score (upvotes - downvotes) → Рейтинг сообщения (голоса «за» — «против»)
- Asked $__count$ non-wiki questions with a total score of $QuestionScore$. → Задал $__count$ авторских вопроса с общим рейтингом, равным $QuestionScore$.
- $Score$/$ScoreRequired$ score → $Score$/$ScoreRequired$ очков рейтинга (из упомянутого выше вопроса)
- Earn at least $score$ total score for at least $answerScoreStr$ non-community wiki answers in the $tagLink$ tag. These users can single-handedly mark $tagLink$ questions as duplicates and reopen them as needed → Заработать не менее $score$ очков рейтинга за минимум $answerScoreStr$ ответов, не отмеченных как общие, на вопросы с меткой $tagLink$. Такие пользователи могут самостоятельно отмечать дубликаты среди вопросов с меткой $tagLink$, а также повторно открывать их.

Comment: Минусатор, объясните свою позицию )