# Несколько вопросов о знаке "Дисциплинированный"

Tags: обсуждение, знаки

Описание знака:

```
Удалить свое сообщение с рейтингом минимум 3 балла.
```

- Под сообщением что понимается? (ответ, вопрос, комментарий, комментарий в чате)
- Возможно будет ревертнуть удаление?
- Баллы это голоса или репутация?

Comment: post - это вопрос или ответ, рейтинг - это голоса. Ревертнуть можно, но не могу сказать, что будет со значком, может и убраться

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Под сообщениями (posts) в нашем стандарте перевода понимаются вопросы и ответы. Комментарии и сообщения в чате != сообщения на сайте.

Вы можете отменить удаление, если вы сами удалили своё сообщение. Если его удалил модератор - то восстановить может только модератор.

Баллы рейтинга - это число, которое написано слева от сообщения, между двумя стрелочками. Баллы рейтинга суммируются [в рейтинги по меткам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1705/181472), но не имеют жесткой связи с репутацией.

Comment: _но не имеют жесткой связи с репутацией._ - как это? 1 балл - 10 репутации. Или это какая-то другая связь имелась ввиду?

Comment: @Grundy 1) голос за, голос против. В итоге 0 рейтинга и +8 репутации.

Comment: @Grundy 2) за один день 30 голосов за. В итоге 30 рейтинга и 200 репутации.

Comment: @Grundy 3) ответ общий. Сколько угодно рейтинга (и можно получить знак "Дисциплинированный"), но нет прироста репутации.

Comment: :-D вот жесткая связь и прописана :-D то есть правила то постоянные и их не так уж много :)

Comment: @Grundy правила-то постоянные, но по рейтингу нельзя точно сказать, сколько репутации было получено за вопрос или ответ.

Comment: Ну если смотреть разбивку на +/- то мне кажется можно

Comment: А, кстати, если удалить вопрос/ответ, получить значок, и восстановить вопрос/ответ - значок останется?

Comment: @Grundy не знаю, не могу проверить, т.к. уже имею этот знак. )

Comment: @Grundy, удалил свой ответ, минут через 5 система наградила, после восстановил ответ, вроде бы не собираются знак отнимать :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, за Духом можно восстанавливать голосованием. Это за модератором только модератор.

Comment: @Grundy Да, останется. Если правильно помню, знаки никогда не отнимаются автоматическим образом (т.е. без действия разработчика SO).

Comment: @PeterOlson знаки за метки отнимаются, включая Эрудита. Остальные - нет.