# Блокировки за тревоги на комментарии и сообщения

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

Нахожусь сейчас в бане на тревоги (за тревоги, приведённые [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2974/199934)). [Отсюда](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/326972)

> Depending on when and how those declined flags were cast, this block could last for as little as a day, and won't ever be longer than a week.

следует, что блокировка длится максимум неделю.

Сегодня с утра мне удалось пометить комментарий тревогой.

[image: Утренняя тревога]

Уже подумал, что закончился общий срок блокировки. Но когда я пробую помечать тревогой «[сообщение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2756/199934)», т. е. вопрос или ответ, ничего не выходит.

[image: Тревога на сообщение]

Комментарии меж тем могу помечать и сейчас.

[image: Тревога на комментарий]

В чём состоит разница в блокировках за тревоги на сообщения и комментарии? Баны на «сообщения» и комментарии раздельные? Находятся ли они в следующей зависимости: «заблокирован за тревоги на комментарии — блокировка на тревоги на комментарии», «заблокирован за тревоги на сообщения — блокировка на тревоги на сообщения»? Так бы и предположил, но, ЕМНИП, в первые дни, после того, как мои тревоги были отклонены, я не мог помечать и комментарии в том числе.

Comment: Вы уверены, что не можете отметить тревогой пост? Если выбрать какой-нибудь пункт, то кнопка "Отметить тревогой" не становится доступной?

Comment: То, что на первом скрине - это предупреждение, а не запрет. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1582/178988

Comment: @Discord, да, сейчас дополнительно проверял на вопросах и ответах. я не могу выбрать ни один пункт. Скриншот выше привёл. КружкИ на нём более тусклые, чем у скриншота тревоги к комментарию. Спасибо.

Comment: @Qwertiy, см. [здесь](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3017/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?noredirect=1#comment9516_3017). У меня «бан»,  а не «предупреждение» (о разнице читал [тут](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/326972)), поскольку отмечать пункты не могу.

Comment: @СашаЧерных блокировка пройдет через 2 дня - 2016-05-09 14:12:15 UTC. В утилитах модератора нет возможности ее снять. Может быть может CM (Николас). Написал ему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зависимостей нет. Блокировка одна на все тревоги, то есть если система блокирует доступ к тревогам в комментариях, отмечать сообщения тревогой вы тоже не сможете.

Comment: Nicolas, как тогда объяснить, что я не мог (уже блокировка снята) помечать тревогами сообщения, но мог комментарии?

Comment: @СашаЧерных К сожалению, не скажу, так как не могу понять всех деталей происходящего на вашем клиенте, но ответ заверял у ребят, которые реализовывали этот функционал.

Comment: Nicolas, проблема как-то не очень похожа на клиентскую. Спасибо, ответ ясен.