# По каким причинам могут быть удалены комментарии?

Tags: поддержка, комментарии

### 1. Вопрос

- Какими правилами руководствуются модераторы Stack Overflow на русском при удалении комментариев? [**Здесь**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2294/199934), — к сожалению, только в двух абзацах, — приведены критерии удаления, но они относятся к «сообщениям», под которыми на этом сайте [**не понимаются комментарии**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2756/199934).

---

### 2. Пример

*Примечание*: мне не принципиален данный конкретный комментарий, а интересуют общие принципы.

Точно помню, что оставлял комментарий к [**данному ответу**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/566775/199934), аргументируя минус. При этом:

- В комментарии не содержалось неуважительных реплик в чей-либо адрес;
- Он был по теме, а не оффтопом;
- Мог принести пользу участникам, поскольку там содержались доводы, почему я не рекомендую применять описанное в ответе решение. Позднее развернул их подробно [**в своём ответе**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/593530/199934).

Согласно [**сообщению на общей Мете**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99818/326972) пользователи не могут удалять чужие комментарии к своим сообщениям, чтобы удалял самостоятельно — тоже такого не припомню. Остаётся вариант с модераторами.

Comment: чужие комментарии могут удалить **только** модераторы, по тревоге или без нее.

Comment: Будет также неплохо, если тот, кто поставил минус моему ответу и плюс другому прокомментирует своё решение. Желательно, основываясь на [**правилах**](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4049/199934). Спасибо.

Comment: [Уже обсуждалось](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33746988#33746988) в чате: `Помните неоднократные предложения ввести обязательные комментарии к минусам? И вот, человек комментирует свой минус — а комментарий получает тревогу "неконструктивный".`

Comment: @Alex, я и сказал это в последнем абзаце. Спасибо.