# Скриншоты вместо кода и сообщений об ошибках

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, ответы

### 1. Проблема

Скриншоты и скринкасты приносят немало пользы; они могут прекрасно иллюстрировать [**сообщения**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2756/199934), а иногда намного легче и лучше показать, чем рассказать. Однако использование скриншотов/скринкастов **вместо** кода и сообщений об ошибках считаю вредным.

Причём скопировать и вставить код либо сообщение об ошибке ненамного труднее, чем вставить скриншот: от авторов сообщений не требуется производить дополнительную работу, отнимающую их время.

---

### 2. Примеры

1. [**Sublime Text 3 не выводит кириллицу при компиляции java**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/581364/199934) — скриншот кода, а не код.
2. [**Проблемы с Composer**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621222/199934) — скриншот сообщения об ошибке, а не сообщение об ошибке.
3. [**Totally/Ultimate Distraction Free Mode (Shift + F11)**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/565790/199934) — пример, где скриншот, на мой взгляд, как раз вполне допустим, поскольку содержание кода не имеет значения.

---

### 3. Аргументы

В меньшей степени аргумент 3.1 может относиться к сообщениям об ошибках равно как и аргумент 3.2 относиться к коду.

#### 1. Скриншоты кода

Когда-то давно мне действительно казалось, что программисты — «звери», знающие наизусть все тонкости и нюансы; только посмотрят — и правильный ответ готов. На самом же деле производимые отвечающим действия зависят от уровня отвечающего и сложности вопроса. Часто отвечающему требуется воспроизвести проблему и самому приступать к отладке.

Так вот переписывать, тратя своё время, код со скриншотов неохота, полагаю, не только мне. А если будет меньше желающих ответить, это ведь невыгодно и самому автору вопроса.

Да, этот пост о «сообщениях», не только лишь вопросах. Если скриншот вместо кода находится в ответе, это, по моему мнению, тоже не очень хорошо, поскольку тем, кто решит кодом воспользоваться, придётся тратить дополнительное время на перепечатывание.

Ответы на некоторые контраргументы:

1. **Используй «Hello World», а не код автора** — поведение инструмента для программирования для «Hello World» и авторского кода может серьёзно различаться.
2. **Используй OCR** — OCR-сервисы и программы порой допускают немало ошибок, особенно если текст на скриншоте мелким шрифтом. Плюс отвечающему придётся тратить на OCR дополнительное время.

#### 2. Сообщения об ошибках

[**Поисковые движки экспериментируют с OCR, но данные технологии не имеют широкого применения**](https://books.google.ru/books?id=1dWUAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%B2+%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85&source=bl&ots=AgGCL4wHO4&sig=yoF5ugPTDaILDrKFbIJbd_MJql0&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXmKSqzPDRAhUCSJoKHX3JB5cQ6AEIUDAI#v=onepage&q=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false). И по опыту: на практике вероятность, что текст из изображения будет распознан и встретится в поисковой выдаче, довольно низка. Т. е. маловероятно, что человека, получивший такую же ошибку, поисковик приведёт к сообщению со скриншотом вместо сообщения об ошибке. Сообщение становится почти бесполезным для других.

---

### 4. Меры

Мнение.

1. **Хорошая** — поставить «профилактический» минус. В комментариях дать ссылку, к примеру, на данное обсуждение, добавив, что если сообщение будет исправлено, то минус будет удалён.
2. **Плохая** — неаргументированный минус (не вижу, чтобы вообще они были бы полезными). Человек не поймёт, за что его минусуют; у неё/него сложится негативное мнение о Stack Overflow на русском; сайт может недосчитываться своих пользовательниц/пользователей.

Важно понимать, что практика скриншотов вместо кода и ошибок распространена на других сайтах; на Тостере, кажется, что их вообще засилье. Авторы вопросов на Stack Overflow могут задавать вопросы также, как это принято на других сайтах.

---

### 5. Вопросы

1. Считает ли сообщество недопустимыми скриншоты вместо кода и сообщений об ошибках?
2. Если да, какие меры стоит предпринимать?

Comment: Проблема скриншотов вместо текста еще и в том, что они не индексируются поисковиками и соответственно поиск, например, по названию ошибки, не выведет на этот вопрос и кто то не получит возможное решение.

Comment: @pavlofff, см. п. 3.2. Спасибо.

Comment: Проблема изображений не только в индексации. Люди часто отключают загрузку изображений на мобильных устройствах, что приводит к тому, что вопрос становится вообще не понятным.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всё должно быть по ситуации. В большинстве случаев текст действительно гораздо лучше скриншотов, но бывают ситуации, когда скриншоты всё же удобнее.

Кстати, я тоже [задавал вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550616/178988) с видео вместо кода. Потому что было вообще непонятно, какие куски кода имеет смысл привести и насколько они понятно покажут проблему.

А вот с тем, что молчаливый минус за скриншот - это плохо, полностью согласен.

Comment: `бывают ситуации, когда скриншоты всё же удобнее` – когда скриншоты могут заменить код или сообщение об ошибке? Дополнить могут, согласен.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Скриншот _может_ показать проблему в UI. У нас на мете много баграпортов по локализации содержат скриншоты как равноправный источник информации.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, когда "у меня IDEA все красным подчеркивает, аааАааааАА"

Comment: @VladD очень правильно сказано. Люблю постить скриншоты багов :)

Comment: @VladD а причем тут вообще Мета? Вопрос об основном сайте.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Это был пример того, что скриншот в принципе _может_ быть адекватным способом рассказать о проблеме. Да, я не привёл подтверждений того, что он может быть адекватным способом рассказать о проблеме _именно на ru.SO_, но, думаю, вы додумаете пример за меня сами.

Comment: Не вижу ни одной ситуации, в которой вместо текста с кодом неработающей программы или текстового сообщения о полученной ошибке уместен скриншот. Пример "с проблемой в UI" относительно размещения проблемного кода и ошибок в нем не очень то удачен, речь идет именно о коде и ошибках, а не уместности скриншотов в вопросах вообще.

Comment: @pavlofff К примеру, вопрос по css анимации можно показать скриншотом "как надо".

Comment: Не соглашусь, для начала можно объяснить непонятные части кода комментариями в самом коде, или же написать в вопросе объяснение тех или иных частей кода, также в тех же скриншотах можно сделать ТОЛЬКО объяснение.

Answer (score 6):

Я считаю, что скриншот вместо проблемного кода или сообщения о ошибке несколько не уместен.

Скриншот вместо текста неудобно читать, труднее воспроизвести у себя для теста и проблемно использовать для поиска по докам\гуглить.

Набирать что-то с скриншота  - это куча потеряного времени, и большинство просто проигнорирует такой вопрос, чем будут с этим возится. Использование OCR нельзя рассматривать как решение, так как сканировать скриншот, чтобы получить из него текст для решения чужой проблемы - это нужно быть очень добрым малым без определенных обязанностей (с массой свободного времени)

Ну и проблема индексации поисковиками, ведь нам (на самом деле больше администрации ресурса) нужен трафик из поисковиков ...

Лично я для таких вопросов предлагаю в комментарии разместить вместо скриншотов код и ошибку текстом, если автор не находит в себе силы сделать это, то про вопрос просто забываю, отвечать на такой вопрос у меня нет ни малейшего желания (и судя по попадавшимся вопросам, у многих тоже)

Насчет относительных трудностей между получением скриншота или текста - я не считаю, что это должно быть обсуждаемым моментом. Человек, который задает вопрос, больше нуждается в помощи, чем отвечающие заинтересованы ему помочь и, конечно, может проделать несколько манипуляций для копирования текста.

Что делать. Указать в комментарии на проблему, и если нет взаимности от автора, то тут уж на свое усмотрение - нравится стучать по клавиатуре - отвечайте, сам по себе скриншот не показатель плохого вопроса. Я просто игнорирую такие вопросы - если автор так и не получит ответов, из комментария он знает почему.