# Правила оформления вопросов. Код в виде скриншотов: Часть вторая

Tags: предложение, справка

**Дисклеймер:**

*С данным вопросом тесно связано следующее обсуждение:* [Скриншоты вместо кода и сообщений об ошибках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4692/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85)
*Данное обсуждение хоть и дополняет текущий вопрос, но не решает проблему, которая будет описана в этом вопросе.*

---

Давеча наткнулся на вопрос от новичка. 
В данном вопросе весь код был приложен в виде скриншотов.
Я, как полагается культурному участнику сообщества, вежливо попросил  так не делать и объяснил почему. 
Объяснил я достаточно подробно(пользователь, кстати уже исправился), но у меня потянулась рука дать ему ссылку на конкретную страницу в справке, в котором бы черным по белому(ну или наоборот, если у вас темная тема) было написано как именно нужно оформлять код в вопросе и в каких случаях допустимы скриншоты, а в каких нет.

Я пошел в справку.
Пробежался по разделу "[Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)", но искомой информации не нашел.
Меня обуяла паника, я обратился в чате за помощью и @andreymal мне прислал ссылку на обсуждение вопроса [Скриншоты вместо кода и сообщений об ошибках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4692/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85)

Я его прочитал...сказать что меня ждало разочарование значит не сказать ничего.
В данном вопросе нет никаких критериев: когда допустимо использовать скриншоты, а когда нет.
**Все что предлагается в ответе:** действовать по ситуации и стараться не ставить "молчаливых минусов".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мы ежедневно десятками отсылаем новичков читать справку и заставляем "нормально" оформлять код в вопросах, а как оказывается все, на что мы можем ссылаться это на коллективный разум, результаты деятельности которого нигде не зафиксированы и на здравый смысл.

**Так не пойдет, братцы) Нужно исправляться!**
Я предлагаю под данным вопросом сделать общий ответ, в рамках которого мы предложим текст для справки, в котором опишем эти самые правила и критерии для оформления кода.
Данный текст мы сможем предложить Николасу, который сможет разместить его в справке.

Comment: Наверное надо как-то красиво сформулировать мысль -- ***все, что м.б. представлено в виде текста должно быть текстом в вопросе***. Тут возникает проблема форматирования (шрифты, цвет  и т.д.). Если эти элементы важны, то **в качестве дополнения к тексту** можно прикладывать изображение

Comment: @avp, спасибо. Да, скриншот может нести полезную информацию и быть дополнением, но не заменой ( как мне кажется ). Вопрос только в том, что делать если его слишком много и что прикладывать в том случае когда ТС не уверен в том, что именно должно быть в вопросе.

Comment: И тут мы возвращамся к теме соотношения здравого смысла и правил. Ничего особенного делать не надо. Все предусмотреть и описать невозможно

Comment: @avp, согласен. Но у нас пока вообще ничего нет. И сообщество закрывает вопросы "низкого качества" просто руководствуясь "здравым смыслом".  Это можно применить ко всем абсолютно правилам SO, и практически везде стоят пояснения и дисклеймеры по данному поводу. Нужно это хотя бы общими словами записать и зафиксировать. Я понемногу начинаю набрасывать текст. Как будет готов - можно будет покритиковать.