# Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?

Tags: обсуждение, форматирование, скриншот

Размещение в вопросах и ответах скриншотов исходного кода, примеров данных, сообщений об ошибках вызывает резко негативную реакцию со стороны участников сообщества. Почему?

Свободный перевод: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)

---

**Каноническая ссылка:** `[Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)`

**Каноническая ссылка 2:** `[Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)`

Comment: Надоело давать ссылку на англоязычную версию. Перевод, конечно, так себе. Не сомневаюсь, что участники найдут более удачные формулировки. Возможно, даже найдётся, чем дополнить сей список. Не стесняйтесь - исправляйте, дополняйте. Это будет полезно.

Comment: странно, мне казалось такое уже было где-то

Comment: @Grundy Я поискал. Нашёл жалобы, но не перевод или обоснование, подобное собранному в теме-оригинале.

Comment: [Скриншоты вместо кода и сообщений об ошибках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4692/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85)

Comment: [Правила оформления вопросов. Код в виде скриншотов: Часть вторая](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11865/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%a7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f)

Comment: В `c#` метке код скринами публикуется несколько раз в неделю: 1) закрываю с причиной _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._ 2) ставлю минус (редко), когда кроме скринов есть еще другие проблемы. 3) иногда оставляю комментарий, если сама суть вопроса может оказаться полезной. 4) никогда не отвечаю на таким образом оформленный вопрос. Примерно в половине случаев автор исправляется.

Comment: спасибо громаднейшее) наконец-то нашелся тот, кто сделал это)

Comment: Ееее......... круто! Думаю это очень нужно....А то моя пятая точка уже полыхает))) особенно от тёмных тем)))

Comment: Мне до сих пор непонятно, почему люди (и это мода новой молодёжи) думают, что скрины - это удобно? Вот правда. Там же логически если рассуждать много минусов найти можно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ИМХО, они просто не понимают, как по другому вставить код с подсветкой.

Comment: [Как скопировать текст из консоли?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/472866/178576)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqESk.jpg

Answer (score 40):

### Почему не следует так делать, чем плохи скриншоты (картинки).

- Исходный код и данные не могут быть скопированы из картинки и затем вставлены в редактор (IDE или fiddle) для воспроизведения проблемы.
- Картинки имеют большой размер, и их трудно читать на небольших экранах мобильных устройств. К тому же они требуют много дискового пространства, которое на мобильных устройствах весьма ограничено, да и трафика уходит куда как больше.
- Картинки могут блокироваться корпоративными Интернет-шлюзами. То же относится и к сайтам, на которых размещаются картинки. В этом случае читатель просто не увидит картинку.
- Текст с картинки нельзя использовать в поиске.
- Картинки просто труднее читать по сравнению с текстом.
- Если кода/данных много, это может потребовать нескольких картинок. Такой вопрос будет читать очень сложно по сравнению с правильно форматированным кодом/текстом. На картинке можно показать не так много строк кода, чтобы они помещались на экране. Весь код может не поместиться в один экран, даже если Вы создали максимально компактный пример, демонстрирующий проблему.
- Скопировать в свой вопрос код или данные и отформатировать их гораздо проще, чем сделать скриншот, разместить его в подходящем месте и вставить ссылку.
- Вы хотите, чтобы мы помогли решить Вашу проблему, причём совершенно бесплатно - затратьте немного усилий и сделайте так, чтобы нам было проще помочь.
- Программы, читающие текст с экрана, не умеют читать текст с картинок - Это создаст проблемы для людей, имеющих проблемы со зрением.
- Картинка, размещённая на стороннем сервере, может стать недоступной, что может сделать вопрос совершенно нечитаемым.
- Другие участники не смогут улучшить вопрос, поправив форматирование кода.
- На скриншоте не удастся обнаружить случаи, когда проблема вызвана неотображаемым символом или символом Юникода, который лишь визуально совпадает с правильным.
- Картинки требуют гораздо больше ресурсов, чем текст - передать 200 байт текста гораздо проще, чем 200 килобайт картинки. Stack Overflow имеет сотни миллионов просмотров в день, а потому каждый лишний передаваемый байт, каждая лишняя затраченная миллисекунда - действительно лишние.
- Некоторые люди используют тёмную схему оформления, и белый фон картинки им просто "бьёт по глазам". А картинка с прозрачным фоном, или картинка с тёмным фоном при избыточном фоновом освещении, может стать просто нечитаемой.
- Большая часть картинки часто бесполезна: визуальные элементы IDE и операционной системы, а так же просто пустое место.

Картинки могут использоваться, но лишь как дополнение, демонстрирующее проблему, если иной способ предоставления не может продемонстрировать её достаточно понятно.

Comment: "Некоторые люди используют тёмную схему оформления, и белый фон картинки им просто "бьёт по глазам"." --- вот кстати я бы написал совсем наоброт... Часто выкладывают скрины с тёмной темой и когда ты днём смотришь на это (с солнышком и прочими прелестями), то не видно абсолютно ничего

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Добавил... посмотри, если что некорректно, поправь.

Comment: `Если кода/данных много, это может потребовать нескольких картинок. Такой вопрос будет читать очень сложно по сравнению с правильно форматированным кодом/текстом.` и `На картинке можно показать не так много строк кода, чтобы они помещались на экране. Весь код может не поместиться в один экран, даже если Вы создали максимально компактный пример, демонстрирующий проблему.` +/- об одном и том же, может объединить в один пункт?

Comment: ещё причина: удалить (изменить) какую-нибудь секретную информацию (пароли, ключи, токены, доменные имена, адреса, личные данные) гораздо проще внутри текста, нежели «замазать» её на картинке.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Исправляйте, добавляйте... хотя наиболее актуально это в варианте, когда изначально такая информация была "прохлопана" и выложена - вот тут действительно поправить текст вопроса и изготовить новый скриншот по простоте несравнимы.

Answer (score 23):

А ответы картинками можно? :)

Просто показать вот такой код...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так делал)) Когда кто-то задавал вопрос картинками. Пусть кто угодно считает как хочет, а я это делал в воспитательных целях (правда всего пару раз)  ))

Comment: Огонь конечно)))

Comment: Что это за шрифт? Это выглядит потрясающе!

Comment: Отличная идея, если код в вопросе картинкой, код в ответе тоже давать такой картинкой :)

Comment: Картинкой на которой ссылка на видео в пару часов на котором код появляется посимвольно :)

Comment: Уж лучше шрифтом https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Redacted+Script

Comment: @VadSim Мы все же программисты, а не медики...

Comment: Если вам не нравится шрифт, пробуйте https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Flow+Block

Comment: Или https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Barcode+39

Comment: Выглядит как рецепт зелья из средневековья...

Comment: Интересно, это какой язык (: ?

Comment: @Зонтик React js, Смог разлечить useEffect и let button = document.createElement('button'). Там еще классы этой кнопке добавляется и onClick вешается.