# Что делать, если участник не хочет приводить код текстом, а не картинкой?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, новички

Есть такой вопрос: [Хочу сделать диаграмму распределения по классам в Pandas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1520787/). Я написал автору стандартный комментарий:

> [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2#12120)

На что он ответил:

> почему? так же куда удобнее

---

Что делать в таких случаях?

Можно было бы перепечатать код с картинки, но во-первых это долго и неудобно, а во-вторых в приведённом вопросе была одна картинка - код и таблица, так что пришлось бы загружать картинку себе, обрезать её по таблице, и только потом перепечатывать код - в общем не очень удобно.

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/186999)

Comment: если вопрос по коду и код не предоставлен - вопрос можно закрыть с соответствующей причиной

Comment: @Grundy а какая причина здесь - соответствующая?

Comment: например: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратите внимание, вопрошающий не соизволил даже открыть пост [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375), и вместо того, чтобы разобраться самостоятельно, спросил в комментарии, хотя ему уже дали ссылку с <s>с 95 тезисами Мартина Лютера</s> 15 тезисами сообщества. И даже когда вопрошающему объяснили, что надо сделать, чтобы улучшить вопрос, он этого не сделал.

**Вывод:**

> Вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; он непонятен или не несёт пользы

То есть ставим минус. Если на вопрос не будет ответов, то он будет удалён Духом Сообщества через месяц. Можно, конечно, вопрос и закрыть. Из всех причин лучше всего подходит <kbd>Не по теме</kbd>

> Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Вроде всё очевидно.