# Нужна ли нам тревога "Код/данные/текст приведены изображением"?

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги, форматирование, скриншот

Нужна ли нам тревога "Код/данные/текст приведены изображением"?

Чаще всего, если в вопросе код/данные/текст приведены изображением, нужно просто писать в комментариях автору чтобы он это исправил, но это не всегда помогает ([Что делать, если участник не хочет приводить код текстом, а не картинкой?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12734/)).

Так вот вопрос: **Нужна ли нам тревога "Код/данные/текст приведены изображением"?**

Comment: Так причина "_Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе_" вполне достаточна. Но можно, конечно, аргументировать, что код на скриншоте тоже код и он есть в вопросе :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В этом случае вопрос можно закрыть по причине:

> Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает**?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

В подавляющем большинстве случаев этого достаточно.

Если же совсем всё плохо, и проблема не только в скриншотах, а в чём-то еще, то есть тревога:

> **Необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством**
>
> У данного вопроса серьёзные проблемы с форматированием или содержанием. Поскольку маловероятно, что его удастся улучшить с помощью правок, этот вопрос нужно удалить.

Либо использовать другие причины для закрытия "непонятна суть вопроса" или "необходимо конкретизировать" в зависимости от контекста.

Считаю, что дополнительный тип тревоги *не требуется*.