# Знаки за репутацию в метках

Tags: поддержка, знаки

Сейчас обратил внимания , что прогресс в получении знаков по меткам отображается не по всем меткам.

Например в моем пользователе:

Лучшая метка R

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом ее нет в списке меток за которые я могу получить знак :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

от чего зависит этот список меток за которые можно получить знак?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы за метку можно было получить знак, необходимо, чтобы по этой метке было задано не менее ста вопросов. На данный момент по [r](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) есть всего 39 вопросов.

Если к моменту публикации сотого вопроса вы уже будете удовлетворять условиям для получения одного из знаков, то при следующем пересчёте рейтингов (раз в сутки) вы получите знак.

[Подробнее об условиях получения знаков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1705/181472)

На эту же механику завязан знак [Эрудит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist). Чтобы на сайте можно было его получить, необходимо существование не менее чем 40 индивидуальных меток, по которым можно получить знак. (Так, на основном сайте у нас Эрудит доступен, а на Мете - нет).