# Баллы рейтинга для получения знака за метку

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Здравствуйте. Меня интересует два вопроса, начисляются ли баллы рейтинга для получения знака за метку в определенных ситуациях:

1. Если дать ответ на вопрос, а к вопросу после этого будет добавлена метка - будут ли начислены баллы, за этот ответ, если метка на вопросе появилась позже?
2. Когда ответ принят, за это дают балл или балл начисляется только за голосование (за/против)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос.

1. Да, будет, но пересчет может произойти с запозданием. (Примерно об этом упоминается в «[Will tag score of all answerers be re-calculated after re-tagging question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122421/)» и «[Will tag score be re-calculated automatically after deleting negative score answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102203/)».) В дополнение, прекрасный ответ @NickVolynkin «[Какие единицы используются при расчете для получения знаков?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1705/6)».
2. Если ваш ответ был принят, вы получите 15 баллов репутации, а автор вопроса, принявший ваш ответ – 2 балла: «[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)». Более подробно про репутацию: «[Что такое репутация? Как можно её заработать (и потерять)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)».

Comment: Да, согласен, ответ хороший. Но меня интересуют не баллы репутации, а баллы за метку для получения знака. С баллами репутации мне все ясно.

Comment: Как я понимаю, именно про баллы за метку и идет речь. Точнее не про сами баллы, а про рейтинг: количество «голосов за» за вычетом «голосов против». Расчет делается для каждой метки вопроса. Если метка удаляется, рейтинг по ней пересчитывается. Как я понимаю, если метку добавить, результат будет аналогичным – пересчет рейтинга.

Comment: Все, открыл статью на http://meta.stackexchange.com/ и все понял. *Повторное добавление тегов вопросов заставит пересчитать баллы тега.*

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а кавычки в ссылку не входят это специально?

Comment: @Grundy [Да, специально](http://rus.stackexchange.com/q/418515/2).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, _Приведенные вами ссылки, все таки рекомендации._ Но ладно :-) пусть так.

Comment: @Grundy, если вы знаете правило, пожалуйста, ответьте в вопросе. Будем все писать более грамотно!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, не, естественно не знаю. Просто лично мне больше нравится, когда кавычки входят в ссылку

Comment: @DenisBubnov я обновил ответ по ссылке, добавил туда пункты по вашим вопросам. Надеюсь, на этом "покрытие" темы стало полным.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо. Ознакомился. Тема действительно стала более покрытой. Я уже читал все это. Все равно спасибо :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, последние две ссылки ведут на одну и ту же страницу