# Как работает рейтинг метки?

Tags: поддержка, метки, справка, репутация, профиль-участника

В справке написано, что для получения серебряного знака необходимо заработать 400 баллов рейтинга за не менее чем 80 ответов. Я был уверен, что рейтинг - это количество полученных балов репутации, но наблюдение за тем, как растёт рейтинг метки java в моём профиле, это опровергает. Я получаю за ответ на вопрос с меткой java 25 балов (15 за принятие ответа и 10 за голос), рейтинг вырастает на единицу. Значит ли, что рейтинг для метки - это количество принятых вопросов? Но тогда информация в справке выглядит странно. Что я упустил?

Comment: Уже был такой вопрос, рейтинг: это итоговое количество голосов

Comment: То есть только голосов ЗА? Без учёта принятия ответов?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev и минус голоса "против". Да.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какие единицы используются при расчете для получения знаков?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1703/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2) Не то чтобы точный дубликат, но ответы там прямо отвечают и на этот.