# Золотой знак по метке

Tags: поддержка, метки, знаки, золотые-знаки

У меня чуть больше 1к репутации. Слышал, что участники с золотым знаком имеют дополнительные привилегии. Как узнать сколько осталось копить, чтобы получить знак  [image: JAVA GOLD BOI] (98% сообщений)?

Comment: [Какие единицы используются при расчете для получения знаков?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1703/186999)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Имеется ввиду репутация по метке - до золота 1000, а не общая репутация пользователя.
К примеру, у вас репутация по метке [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) на данный момент 71, когда она станет 100, при 20 ответах, вы получите бронзовый знак по данной метке.
Аналогично бронзовому знаку, есть требования по серебрянному и золотому знаку.
Вы можете настроить отслеживание данного процесса в меню "Активность" вашего профиля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отслеживать вы можете любую метку, на которую вы давали хоть раз ответ.

По серебрянному знаку требования: 400 баллов и 80 ответов.
По золотому знаку: 1000 баллов и 200 ответов
Выполняете требования системы и необходимый знак ваш.

Comment: Причём галка на ответе не учитывается как балл.

Comment: @AK, какие баллы учитываются в связанном ответе :-)