# Не добавились баллы в метку

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, поддержка

Уже несколько раз замечал, что после того, как мои вопросы: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117848/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-type-%D0%BE%D1%82-isinstance), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117852/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-pass)

или ответы: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115839/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-10-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF/1118066#1118066), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117732/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E/1117787#1117787), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1114544/%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-stdin-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-fmt-scanlnstr/1114640#1114640)

оценивались участниками положительными голосами, я не получал новых баллов в рейтинг по меткам:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по всему, это означает, что я неправильно понимаю механику начисления баллов по меткам. Как они начисляются?

Comment: Учитываются только ответы. Пересчёт идёт не сразу, иногда видно изменение только на следуюший день.

Comment: Угу. Возможный дубликат вопроса: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1703/213987